# Representations of an algebra

Tags: representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I am studying the representations of the following algebra:
$$A=\Bbb C\langle x,y,z\rangle/ \langle zx=0,yz=0, z=xy-yx\rangle$$
Do you know how to attack the problem of classifying all its representations?

Here I recollect the facts that have been reached until now (in comments or in my attempts):

- The center of $A$ is $\Bbb C\langle yx\rangle $ (and note that $ (yx)^n =y^n x^n$ by induction)
- Every monomial is equivalent to one of the form $y^ax^by^c$ with $a \le b$, and these monomials are distinct.
- There is a surjective map $A \to R:=\Bbb C[x,y]$, so we have all the representation of the 2-variable ring. Call them rep. of commutative type. 
  Finite dimensional commutative representations can be expressed as a sum of indecomposable representations, and finite dim indecomposable representations are of the form $x \to \lambda I + N, y \to \mu I + N$ where $N$ has 1 on the superdiagonal and 0 elsewhere. This is just Jordan decomposition (+ the observation that if two matrices commute, they have a common Jordan basis; furthermore, they must have the same jordan form to commute). EDIT: This seems to be **false**. Infact, if $J_n$ is a nilpotent jordan block, $J_n$ and $J_n^2$ commute but they do not have a common Jordan basis. Any hints?
- There is a surjective map $A \to B:= \Bbb C \langle x,y \rangle / \langle yx =0 \rangle $. In this algebra every monomial has the form $x^a y^b$. Using this, one can verify that the derived series for $B$ is $DB= \Bbb C \langle x^a y^b \rangle _{a,b \ge 1}$, and $D^2B = 0$. Furthermore, it holds $B/DB \simeq \Bbb C[x,y]/(xy)$ and $DB \simeq \Bbb C[x_n]/ (x_n x_m)$.
- Every irreducible (but not every indecomposable) representation factors through $R$ or $B$. Infact, if $z=0$, then it factors through $R$. If $z \neq 0$, then $yz=0$ implies that $y$ is not invertible. By Schur Lemma, $yx$ in the center implies that $yx= \lambda I$. But $yx$ is not invertible, thus $yx=0$, i.e. the representation factors through $B$.
- If $x$ or $y$ are mapped to invertible matrices, then the rep. is of commutative type ($z=0$).

Thank you!

Comment: Suppose $V$ is an irreducible representation. Since $yx\in Z(A)$, we have that $yx$ acts as a scalar multiplication, i.e. $yx\cdot v =\lambda v$. If $V$ is finite-dimensional, we get that $\text{Tr}(yx)=\lambda \dim(V)$.  I was wondering whether you can extract information about $\dim(V)$ from this, but I cannot immediately see something.

Comment: Can you explain how you prove that $z^2 = 0$, I have trouble seeing that.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I can clearly see why $yz$ commutes with the image of the representation, but to conclude that it acts as a scalar multiplication wouldn't you need it to commute with all of $GL(V)$?

Comment: Ok, you are right: they are indecomposable. But all representations splits as a sum of indecomposable representations, so they are the bricks we are searching for!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: It is Schur Lemma. If $V$ is irreducible and $f$ commutes with all the elements, then $f$ is an intertwining operator $:V \to V$. Now take an eigenvalue $\lambda $ of $f$. The ker of $f-\lambda I$ is a ontrivial subrepresentation of $V$, thus it is all $V$, i.e. $f=\lambda I$.

Comment: @Mathematician42: Indeed, your observation yields 
$yx=0, z^2=0$, $z\neq 0$. for non commutative representations. Infact $yz=0$ implies that $y$ is not invertible, and $yx= \lambda I$ implies $\lambda =0$. Furthermore, $z^z= (xy-yx)z=xyz=0$.

Comment: Furthermore, $yx=0$ implies automatically all the other relations. Thus irreducible representations of non commutative type comes from $\mathbb{C} \langle x,y \rangle / \langle yx=0 \rangle$. Of course, we don't know anything about non commutative indecomposable rep with this reasonings..

Comment: The derived series of the last algebra has length 2. Infact, you can verify that every monomial can be written as $x^ay^b$, and 
$D B$ is generated by monomials with $a,b \ge 1$; all of these have commutator 0,so $D^2B=0$. In particular, it is solvable.